# What make a graph 3-balanced but not 4-balanced and locally balanced and global balanced?

Tags: graph-theory, signed-graphs

$1)$ A signed graph $G$ is N-balanced if every circuit of length at most N is positive. Give an example of a signed graph which is 3-balanced but not 4 balanced?

I tried drawing a square and made it 3 balance and not 4 balanced but what throws me off is that it says circuit at most N is positive ? does that affect the number of positive signs i must have?

$2)$ A signed graph is locally balanced at vertex u if every circuit containing u is positive. Show that a signed graph may be locally balanced at some vertex u without being (globally) balanced.

I'm not to sure about my answer but i just want someone to check it but idk how to post it since it hand drawn.

Comment: Take picture with mobile and upload, or describe it. E.g. square with edges weight -1 has no non-positive circuits of length 3, and at least 1 circuit of length 4 that is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare to my examples ;)

1. A square with edge weight -1 is 3 balanced (it has no 3 circuits, so no-non-positive ones). It is not 4-balanced
2. Two separate triangles, one with all edges -1 and one with all edges +1. Any $u$ on the second one is locally balanced. Any $v$ on the first one is not locally balanced, to the whole graph is not locally balanced.

Comment: so basically my answer for number 1 the square was the right path all i had to do was make 3 edge +1  and the last side -1 :o  and for 2) i drew 2 triangle like you but its both connected makiing something like a triangle with height down the middle

Comment: your first example adds up to 2, they should all be -1. A bowtie for 2 is also ok,

Comment: but it was given "A signed graph G is N-balanced if every circuit of length at most N is positive" the positive so it doesn't matter if it -1?

Comment: and if all should be -1 how is that balanced?  i thought all -1 means it unbalanced

Comment: What makes a circuit positive? I think the sum of the values of the edges. So to make it unbalanced, we need a circuit with edge-sum negative or zero. If all edges in a square are -1, there is no 3-circuit. And on empty set, all circuits are positive.